# codeigniter png type image uploading with watermark,giving wrong image

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, upload, watermark

I have uploaded this image: [uploaded image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cW5G8.jpg)

And result image was this: [Watermark image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6ZZJ.jpg)

My code function is working fine to png type images and others.only happening for this image only.i cannot find any answer for
related this.please help anyone. this is the code i have used to image upload.please check this and give any answer related to this

```
$this->watermark->watermarkCopy();
$this->watermark->resize($width, $height);
$this->watermark->add($temp_auction_listing['temp_auction_listing']['link_1'], $width, $height);
```

This is watermark functions

```
 public function watermarkCopy() {
            $source = 'images/watermark/wartermark-png.png';
            $watermarkcopy['image_library'] = 'gd2';
            $watermarkcopy['source_image'] = $source;
            $watermarkcopy['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
            $watermarkcopy['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
            $watermarkcopy['quality'] = '100%';
            $watermarkcopy['new_image'] = 'images/watermark/watermarkCopy.png';
            $watermarkcopy['overwrite'] = FALSE;

            $this->load->library('image_lib');
            $this->image_lib->initialize($watermarkcopy);
            if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) {
                echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
            }
    }

  public function resize($width, $height) {
        $settings['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $settings['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $settings['quality'] = '100%';
        $settings['width'] = $width / 2;
        $settings['height'] = $height / 2;
        $settings['source_image'] = 'images/watermark/watermarkCopy.png';
        $this->image_lib->initialize($settings);
        $this->image_lib->resize();
    }

 public function add($url, $width, $height) {
        ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');
        $config['source_image'] = $url;
        $config['wm_type'] = 'overlay';

        $config['wm_overlay_path'] = 'images/watermark/watermarkCopy.png';
        $config['new_image'] = $url;
        $config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'center';
        $config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'middle';
        $config['padding'] = '50%';
        $config['wm_opacity'] = '50';
        $config['wm_x_transp'] = '3';
        $config['wm_y_transp'] = '3';
        $config['quality'] = '100%';

        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);

        if (!$this->image_lib->watermark()) {
            echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I didn't get what you exactly want....!Pls explain properly

Comment: actually this is the scenario.i uploaded image to my system as png type.my image upload function has watermark function.when i upload this image,it is giving ugly image.but this function perfectly when i uploading jpg type images

Comment: I think your watermark image is overlapping your main image..so change image quality and hight/width of watermark image...I can't help you more because difficult to sattle in the situation you are! For more reference refer  "Watermarking Preferences" in official doc

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/image_lib.html

Comment: @Kunal the official doc's now moved http://www.codeigniter.com/docs

Comment: @kunal,wolfgang thank you very much